# Get the rooms in which you have been invited

Tags: xmpp, chatroom

There is a way to get the rooms in which you have been invited?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, such information is not stored on the server. You receive an invitation once, as a message - and must handle it then or store it yourself. For the format of invitations, see [XEP-0045: Inviting a user to a room](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite).

You can also save rooms you want to remember as "bookmarks", see [XEP-0048](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html).